# How can I efficiently partition a list of numbers into a number of nonoverlapping buckets efficiently where there are potentially many buckets?

Tags: performance, optimization

I wrote some code to assign items to a number of buckets.

I have N many buckets of Y many types. And Y numbers. How do you determine all the buckets that each Y number is part of?

A Y number is in a bucket if it is >= start of the bucket range and <= end of the bucket range. It's kind of similar to collision detection.

I am trying to find what user bucket the user 5607 falls into, what thread bucket thread 11 fits into and what server bucket server 3 falls into

I think the Big O notation of my solution is N buckets for the number of buckets.

Is there a faster approach to dividing a list of Y numbers into N buckets?

```
from operator import itemgetter
buckets2 = {
  "buckets": [
    {"type": "user", "name": "users-bucket1", "start": 0, "end": 5000},
    {"type": "user", "name": "users-bucket2", "start": 5001, "end": 10000},
    {"type": "user", "name": "users-bucket3", "start": 10001, "end": 15000},
    {"type": "server", "name": "server-bucket1", "start": 0, "end": 3},
    {"type": "server", "name": "server-bucket2", "start": 4, "end": 7},
    {"type": "server","name": "server-bucket3", "start": 8, "end": 10},
    {"type": "thread", "name": "threads-bucket1", "start": 0, "end": 4},
    {"type": "thread", "name": "threads-bucket2", "start": 5, "end": 9},
    {"type": "thread", "name": "threads-bucket3", "start": 10, "end": 14}
    ]
 }

 buckets2["buckets"].sort(key=itemgetter("start"), reverse=True)

 def route2(routing_information):
    buckets = {}
    for item in buckets2["buckets"]:
       if item["end"] >= routing_information[item["type"]]:
           buckets[item["type"]] = item["name"]
    return buckets

 print(route2({ "server": 3, "user": 5607, "thread": 11}))
```

This gives

```
{'user': 'users-bucket2', 'thread': 'threads-bucket3', 'server': 'server-bucket1'}
```

This code shall be called very frequently, so I want it to be fast.

Comment: I can't read your code because I'm not familiar with the syntax, but it looks like you're scanning all bucket types for each query. You know what bucket type you're looking for, so just scan the relevant ranges for the argument's bucket type, sorted on start so you can end the scan once the result is found, assuming there is always one and only one result.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Simon. The problem is I need to retrieve multiple bucket numbers per request. I want to know the bucket positions of all 3 keys at once and look up something based on those numbers.